# Проверка схемы СПП

Tags: синтаксический-разбор, сложное-предложение

Человек уединяется, чтобы поплакать, но изначально он не одинок: когда  человек плачет, он просто не хочет, чтобы кто-нибудь был сопричастен его слезам.

Проверьте, пожалуйста, правильна ли схема СПП?

**[... , (чтобы...),...]: (когда...), [... ], (чтобы...).**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Схема:  [... ], (чтобы...), но[...]: (когда...), [... ], (чтобы...).

Answer (score 0):

Схема-то правильная. Однако это предложение классифицируется как сложное многочленное предложение, это не СПП.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы составил такую схему:

{[… ], (чтобы…)}, но[…]: {(когда...), [... ], (чтобы…)}